# Horizontal pod autoscaling in openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

does open shift actively monitor cpu for all the running processes or just the first process that was run.

i am running a service that is configured to use horizontal auto scaling capabilities.
i have hawkuler metrics and heapster setup and working as expected
i have set my resource limits and target cpu utilization at 50%.
once the pod hits cpu >50 i can see it scale up to 3 pods which is the max that i have in my configuration.

my question is does it monitor all the 3 pods at this point ?
also, is there a way to scale up in steps, like bring up one more pod and if the cpu is above 50% then bring up another on and so on or the maximum number of pods configured will be brought up immediatley once the cpu utlization on the 1st pod hits >50%

Comment: The autoscaler generally  tries to scale in increments, and does take into consideration the proportionality of the metrics - so going from 3->4 would result in a period of wait before going 4->5.  It does monitor all pods.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it's by pod.

Ex. Pod 1 goes over your CPU limit, so Pod 2 is deployed. 5 minutes later, Pod 2 goes over your CPU limit, and Pod3 is deployed.